# Numbers whose prime factors all have odd exponent

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $S$ denote the set of natural numbers $m$ with the property that for all prime powers $p^k || m$ we have $k \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.

What is the asymptotic density of $S$?

Note that $S$ contains all prime numbers and more generally, all square-free numbers, so that $\liminf_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\# (S \cap [1,X])}{X} \geq \frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: You could try to compute the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n \in S} n^{-s}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like zeta(3) times the square free density? Gerhard "Being Somewhat Thick About This" Paseman, 2018.10.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dirichlet series $L (s)=\sum_{n \in S} n^{-s} $ has the Euler product expression
$$L (s) = \prod_p \frac{1+p^{-s}-p^{-2s}}{1-p^{-2s}}.$$
So $S $ has analytic density
$$\mu (S) = \operatorname{Res}_{s=1} L(s) = \lim_{s \to 1} \frac{L(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \prod_p \frac{1+1/p-1/p^2}{1+1/p}$$
as can also be seen by an informal argument. We can also rewrite this as
$$ \mu(S) = \prod_p \bigl(1-\frac{1}{p(p+1)}\bigr) = \prod_p \frac{1-2/p^2+1/p^3}{1-1/p^2}$$
I don't expect this Euler product to have a nice expression since the roots of the Euler factor $1+X-X^2$ in the numerator are not roots of unity, so the product cannot be expressed, at least in an obvious way, in terms of values of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: In fact the last expression you write can be written as $\prod_p \left(1 - \frac{2p-1}{p^3}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1} = \zeta(2) C$, where $C = \prod_p \left(1 - \frac{2p-1}{p^3}\right)$ is known as the care-free constant. Very interesting!

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao I didn't know this constant had a name. In fact, I don't know anything about these curious Euler products (are they periods? and so on). I also like the alternative expression $\mu(S) = \prod 1-1/(p (p+1)) $.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao's comment gives a numerical answer of .704441

Comment: @MattF. Numerical evaluation of these constants is indeed not easy. There is a lot of interesting information at http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/moree/Moree.en.html They can get 1000 digits of accuracy in reasonable time (in 1999!). So for $\mu(S)=\prod 1-f/g$ with $f=1$ and $g=p(p+1)$ the numerical value can be found at http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/moree/Moree-details.en.shtml#t10-cfree

Comment: I don't understand the transition between the first display and the second where the Residue has a 1+1/p in the denominator. Is there a typo or a manipulation I am missing? Gerhard "Questionable Minds Wish To Know" Paseman, 2018.10.04.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I tried to clarify that point.

Comment: Thank you. I can now make my way down to just before the last inequality. Thank you for repairing that part of my ignorance.  Gerhard "In Need Of Much Repair" Paseman, 2018.10.05.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the desired set is the disjoint union of (the rad(n) multiples of) squarefree numbers times n^2 as n ranges over all positive integers, which is like (zeta(3) + 1/64 + 3/512 + 2/729 + 1/1728 + 7/4096 + ...)/zeta(2) for the density.

Gerhard "Doing This On Minimal Caffeine" Paseman, 2018.10.04.

Comment: The terms listed come to .746882, which is bigger than the accepted answer.

Comment: I'll reconsider my thinking on this. I think it should be something like zeta(c)/zeta(2) though, where c is between 2 and 3 and zeta(c) stands for sum 1/(rad(n)n^2).  Thanks for checking this answer. Does a straightforward computation tend  to the accepted answer? Gerhard "Will Drink Some More Coffee" Paseman, 2018.10.04

Comment: +1 for the caffeine stuff. (Yes, I know, I'm being unprofessional a likely in violation of a few minor MO rules.)